# php how to add two where in single query

Tags: php, mysql

i have following sql query, everything works fine but when i put **"and posted_date<>$datetime"**  its not retrieving data as per given command.

```
$datetime="0000-00-00";

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_table where category_id=$cat1 or 
pid=$par or gpid=$gpar and posted_date<>$datetime
ORDER BY autoid desc limit $no2,$cacount")

or die(mysql_error());
```

please check is that line is ok maybe i am doing mistake somewhere **where category_id=$cat1 or pid=$par or gpid=$gpar and posted_date<>$datetime**

maybe i need two where one for or and another for and...

Thanks

Comment: Does the `posted_date` condition go with the `gpid` condition, or should it always be checked?  You need to group in `()` like `where (category_id=$cat1 or 
pid=$par) or (gpid=$gpar and posted_date<>$datetime)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to group your condition and use `DATE()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_table 
where (category_id=$cat1 or 
       pid=$par or gpid=$gpar) AND DATE(posted_date) <> DATE($datetime)
ORDER BY autoid desc 
LIMIT $no2, $cacount
```